# best way of design the relational model for hibernate

Tags: hibernate, database-design, orm

What is the best way design entity relational model

1. Fist design E-R diagram then design Domain object model?
2. Fist design Object model(Entity classes ) and then create database tables cording to Entity model?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I usually do the following:

1. In plain English, define what you want to build, exploring the relationships without being bogged down in UML ("a User had many Properties", for instance)
2. Once you reach a basic inflection point where you have a good basic design, start building out Entities, configuring Hibernate to `update` to keep your Java code and the DB in sync
3. Rinse and repeat